# How can I decrypt the Messages sent from log4j over a socket?

Tags: java, log4j

can someone tell me how to decrypt the messages I get at the socket from org.apache.log4j.net.SocketAppender?
I tried the Chainsaw-sources but I didn't find anything there :/

Or where does the message in log4j get encrypted?

Thanks

Comment: ... messages may be cryptic but shouldn't be encrypted. log4j usually produces plain text messages.

Comment: I am sorry, I meant how to de-serialize them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The messages are not encrypted.  They are LoggingEvent objects that have been serialized using a Java ObjectOutputStream : see [org.apache.log4j.net.SocketAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/net/SocketAppender.html).  One way to read them is to use [Chainsaw](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/chainsaw/package-frame.html), but you could always deserilize them yourself by wrapping the remote socket string in a Java ObjectInputStream, and replicating what Chainsaw does to read the events.

Answer (score 1):

A logging source uses log4j to send log events to sinks like the console, a file or a socket. log4j doesn't chang the log messages, it just provides an API to collect and distribute the messages and provides some means to format log messages.

So if the messages are encrypted, then it's the sender that provides encrypted messages.

It could help if you edit your question and provide a small sample of an encrypted log messages.

Answer (score 0):

Chainsaw uses a SocketReceiver to process events sent by SocketAppender.

See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/companions/receivers/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/net/SocketReceiver.html